# How to declare volatile variables in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to convert to Swift from Objective-C code like following;

```
int sum = 0;
x = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sum += x;
}
```

x is accessible from other threads. So x is declared as a volatile variable.

```
volatile int x;
```

How should I write this code in Swift?

**Edited**

Sorry for my bad pseudo code.

Just I wanted to read the latest value property or field not from thread cache.
Java volatile makes that possible. So does Objective-C volatile. ( does it?)

Comment: `volatile` does not make a variable accessible from other threads. It is used to indicate that a variable behaves like a hardware register. Use a mutex lock instead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the original premise is incorrect as volatile does not do as  you claim so we can't convert it

Comment: Sorry for my bad pseudo code. I know what Potatoswatter said.
On porting my Objective-C code, volatile is needed, because other thread may update the variable x and references need to indicate the latest value.

Comment: @MitsuakiIshimoto: I'd declare your Objective-C code as broken. volatile is neither needed nor helpful for communication between multiple threads. I recommend downloading the latest version of the C Standard (which applies to Objective-C as well) and studying it. Most people just use @ synchronized or a mutex which gives all the needed guarantees. Some people look at the functions in the C Standard for accessing shared variables. volatile does _nothing_ for you.

Comment: Here's an interesting discussion regarding this question https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46256

Comment: @Potatoswatter  Yes this is not a case for `volatile` which is only useful for _reading_ purposes to ensure seeing the latest value. Any updates require full  synchronization for that memory address.

Comment: @javadba It’s worse: C++ requires explicit synchronization even for reads and volatile fails even that. It is suitable for synchronizing with something that is thread-local yet asynchronous, such as an interrupt handler or a genuine hardware register.

Comment: @Potatoswatter  In C/C++ 25 years ago I used `mutex`'s  which is the heavy-duty approach you mention: I have not done heavy lifting in `c` languages since java came out.  On the `jvm` 1.5 (2004) memory model  the `volatile` is sufficient for ensuring read consistency .  I'm interpreting from your comment that there is no lightweight read-only synchronization mechanism in pure c++?

Comment: @javadba We have `std::atomic`.

Comment: that does read to be quite similar if not the same  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no equivalent to `volatile` in Swift.

In Swift you have access to more potent means of expressing global synchronicity of values than the `volatile` keyword - which does not provide any kind of atomicity guarantees, and must be used with locks to establish critical sections.  For example, you might choose locks to synchronize read and write access to a variable.  You might choose to use an [MVar](https://github.com/typelift/Concurrent/blob/master/Sources/Concurrent/MVar.swift) to indicate that a variable should only have 1 possible valid state across multiple threads.

Or you might choose to simply not express the problem in Swift.  If you're looking for the exact behavior of a `volatile` variable (which, in your situation, sounds unlikely), stick with C and C++.

Comment: This is a correct treatment of the topic. There _are_ times that `volatile` is useful but they are uncommon and not in the wheelhouse of `swift`

Comment: Too bad `MVar` has "`All rights reserved.`" right above it, meaning without a written permission, you are not allowed to use it in any way (even if it's `README.md` mentions MIT license).

Comment: Maybe someone ask Apple to kindly stop spamming those automatically?

Comment: That's why the first thing I do after Xcode creates a new file is, remove every single byte in said file (but sometimes I leave the `import Foundation`).

Comment: The only good thing about Xcode spamming "`... All rights reserved.`" is that, future readers can detect a licensing noob instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I will expand on @potatoswatter's (excellent) comments .  There are a couple of misunderstandings here

- `Volatile` has nothing to do with accessibility
- `Volatile` is not a sufficient construct here since it is ensures `read` consistency to threads when they access that variable.  Your use case is involving `mutations` to `x` and thus requires `synchronization` that is a more thorough concurrency construct.  This is a moderately advanced concept and is not in the wheelhouse of `swift`.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no equivalent to `volatile` in Swift 5, **but** there is no need to be any equivalent, at least not if your variable is a class' member-variable.

The `volatile` keyword known of `C`, `C++`, `Objective-C`, `Objective-C++` or `Java` language simply does ask the compiler to kindly **not** cache the variable's value (and instead read the related memory each time).

Also as other answers/comments mention, for OP's case, `volatile` was not enough to begin with (and OP shall use lock).

### Example

Swift does not seem to have such fancy compile-time caching for class-members at least, hence no need for `volatile` keyword, and we can instead do:

```
public class Volatile<T> {
    public var value: T;

    public init(_ defaultValue: T) {
        self.value = defaultValue;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var myVariable = Volatile("my value");
```

Or:

```
var myVariable: Volatile<String> = .init("my value");
```