# How to create volatile boolean in Swift?

Tags: multithreading, swift, atomic

I want to execute some task on background and add an ability to cancel the task.

Something like:

```
while !isCanceled && someOtherCondition() {
    doSome()
}
```

And cancel task from another thread:

```
func cancel() {
    isCanceled = true
}
```

In Java I can declare isCancelled volatile and it will be enough. How can I do this in Swift?

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954537/swift-atomic-boolean) may be relevant.

Comment: Possibly also the comments to the the Q here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971489/how-to-declare-volatile-variables-in-swift

Comment: why don't use a delegate?

Comment: please note that `volatile` does not mean `atomic` and should not be assumed to ever confer thread safety in C or C++, instead you should use actual language level [atomics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) which swift doesn't have yet.

Comment: If you’re creating a cancellabke “task”, is there a reason you’re not using [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation)?

Comment: You can create a task that performs your operations and cancel it at any point with Swift's structured concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

Seems this is your answer:

> Swift does not (yet) have a well-defined memory model, so there’s no
>   direct equivalent of C’s volatile. Having said that, C didn’t have a
>   well-defined memory model until C11 either, so you can go a long way
>   without one.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46256